# Add a pause before further execution in mIRC

Tags: sockets, irc, mirc

So I've been thinking for like over an hour but did not arrive any conclusion with this script. I basically am trying to add a "status check" for 3 IRC servers via mIRC sockets. The problem I'm facing is that the execution jumps over to the next step without the socket connection being completed hence it returns a false  value i.e Offline.

I tried using timer before goto commands but that returns ' not found'

Code:

```
on *:text:!stats:#: {
  sockopen IRCAurora aurora.irchound.tk 6667
  sockopen IRCKepler kepler.irchound.tk 6667
  sockopen IRCJupiter jupiter.irchound.tk 6667

  sockpause IRCAurora
  sockpause IRCKepler
  sockpause IRCJupiter

  :true
  msg $chan ----STATUS----
  goto check1
  halt

  :check1
  if ($sock(IRCAurora,pause) == 1) {
    msg $chan 1Aurora -  9Online
  }
  else {
    msg $chan 1Aurora -  4Offline 
  }
  goto check2
  halt

  :check2
  if ($sock(IRCJupiter,pause) == 1) {
    msg $chan 1Jupiter -  9Online 
  }

  else {
    msg $chan 1Jupiter -  4Offline
  }

  goto check3
  halt

  :check3
  if ($sock(IRCKepler,pause) == 1) {
    msg $chan 1Kepler -  9Online
  }
  else {
    msg $chan 1Kepler -  4Offline 
  }
  halt
}
```

I know one solution is simply set up a php bot, but I want it on mIRC.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind .. I've already found the solution for the problem. Simple needed to add an alias function (that replies if socket pause if true / false) with a timer.

Solved code:

```
on *:text,loaddservers:#: {
  if (%admin. [ $+ [ $nick ] ] = 1) { 
    msg $chan All default servers are now being loaded.
    set %server1 aurora.irchound.tk
    set %server2 jupiter.irchound.tk
    set %server3 kepler.irchound.tk
  }
  else {
    msg $chan Access denied.
  }
}

;Create socket connection to servers on trigure.

on *:text:,status*:#: {
  if ($2 = all) {
    sockopen IRCAurora %server1 6667
    sockopen IRCKepler %server2 6667
    sockopen IRCJupiter %server3 6667
    set %chan $chan
    msg $chan Connecting to servers...
    msg $chan >>>Status of all servers<<<
    timer2 1 5 checkall
  }
  if ($2 = aurora) {
    sockopen IRCAurora %server1 6667
    set %chan $chan
    msg $chan Connecting to server $2 $+ ...
    timerAURORA 1 5 checkaurora
  }
  if ($2 = kepler) {
    sockopen IRCKepler %server2 6667
    set %chan $chan
    msg $chan Connecting to server $2 $+ ...
    timerKEPLER 1 5 checkkepler
  }
  if ($2 = jupiter) {
    sockopen IRCJupiter %server3 6667
    set %chan $chan
    msg $chan Connecting to server $2 $+ ...
    timerJUPITER 1 5 checkjupiter
  }
}

;Aliases for each server status response.

alias checkaurora {
  if ($sock(IRCAurora,pause) == 1) {
    msg %chan 1Aurora -  9Online
  }
  else {
    msg %chan 1Aurora -  4Offline 
  }
  halt
}

alias checkjupiter {
  if ($sock(IRCJupiter,pause) == 1) {
    msg %chan 1Jupiter -  9Online
  }
  else {
    msg %chan 1Jupiter -  4Offline 
  }
  halt
}

alias checkkepler {
  if ($sock(IRCKepler,pause) == 1) {
    msg %chan 1Kepler -  9Online
  }
  else {
    msg %chan 1Kepler-  4Offline 
  }
  halt
}

alias checkall {
  if ($sock(IRCAurora,pause) == 1) {
    msg %chan 1Aurora -  9Online
  }
  else {
    msg %chan 1Aurora -  4Offline 
  }
  goto check2
  halt

  :check2
  if ($sock(IRCJupiter,pause) == 1) {
    msg %chan 1Jupiter -  9Online 
  }

  else {
    msg %chan 1Jupiter -  4Offline
  }

  goto check3
  halt

  :check3
  if ($sock(IRCKepler,pause) == 1) {
    msg %chan 1Kepler -  9Online
  }
  else {
    msg %chan 1Kepler -  4Offline 
  }
}
```

NOTE: I've excluded some part of the script that's not related to the question.. so you may find some undefined variables.